# How to submit a buy offer that gets incorporated to a bid entry with the same price

Tags: offer, manageofferoperation

An order book shows a bid entry, for example:

```
12:
amount: "758.2907668"
price: "11.1111111"
price_r: {n: 100, d: 9}
```

I submit a `manageBuyOffer` with `buyAmount` `".01"` and `price` at `"11.1111111"`. I expected the bid entry to increase by .01, and thus to 758.3007668. But instead, the order book returns a new entry at the same price:

```
13:
amount: "0.3333312"
price: "11.1111111"
price_r: {n: 111111111, d: 10000000}
```

with the prior entry remaining the same. The order book thus ends up with two bid entries with the same 11.1111111 price.

I would like to know how do I manipulate the `buyAmount` and `price` parameters so that the new offer gets consolidated with the first one.

I do not encounter this issue when submitting sell offers.

I reckon it has to do with the `price_r`, as indeed I do not encounter the problem when I submit the `price` parameter as a ratio with the same values as those of the first offer, i.e., `price: {n: 100, d: 9}`. This issue could thus be stated otherwise as: given only the `buyAmount` and the `price` parameter in a `string` format, how does one arrive at the `numerator` and the `denominator` of the price so that the new offer gets incorporated with the old offer that has the same `price string`.

Comment: In my experience, you should work with `price_r` and use `price` only to display the price to the user.

Comment: I would want to. But if I use the price_r parameter I still produce a different entry if I do not match the price_r of the old offer I wish my new offer to be incorporated. The problem is to get the price_r of the old offer given the price. I am beginning to think its impossible to work backwards. The price_r of the offer do not always match the price.

Comment: The `price_r` of the offer **always** matches the price because that's how prices are represented. `price` is a way to display `price_r` in an human-readable format.

Comment: For example, 100/9=11.1111111111 (not 11.1111111).

Comment: A price of `100/9` means it takes 9 units of buying to get 100 units of selling asset. That's the price used in the transaction. The `price` field is an human readable representation of `100/9`. You should use `price_r`.

Comment: I understand. The problem is the user sees 11.1111111, and he expects his offer to be incorporated into the same offer entry if he enters the same price. But alas, his offer appears as a separate entry in the order book. What I wish to know is whether there is a way to derive 100/9 from 11.1111111, so that when a user types the latter, behind the scenes, the program would convert 11.1111111 to 100/9 so that his new offers gets incorporated into the old offer.

Comment: The underlying problem is that `100/9 != 11.1111111`, that's the result of truncation. Clearly the price of `400000001 / 36000000` is different from `100/9`, but they both have the same first 7 decimal digits and so they are both represented as `11.1111111` in `price`.

Comment: Shall I take it that in this particular instance, given only the information 11.1111111 and being allowed only to enter the price with max 7 decimals, a user cannot expect to get his offer incorporated into the old offer entry?

Comment: Yes that's my understanding. I will post is as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the underlying problem is that the number `100/9` has infinite decimal digits and cannot be represented as string. The price you see, `11.1111111` is a truncation of `11.11111111.... = 100/9`. When you enter the number `11.1111111` the SDK correctly converts it to its fractional representation `111111111/10000000`.

The only way to get around this is to always use fractional prices.